# Python - nested lists - efective checking

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a nested list and char variable:

```
colors =    [
        ("r", [255,0,0]),
        ("g", [0,255,0]),
        ("b", [0,0,255]),
        ("y", [255,0,0]),
        ("p", [255,0,255])
            ]   

char_to_check="b"
```

How can I (in the most efficient way) check:
1. if **char_to_check** exists in nested list **colors** index  (r, g, b, etc..) 
and
2. if exists (**char_to_check**) provide values for this char from **colors** (for example 255,0,0)
else return error (any kind)

Comment: Use a `dict` with your chars as keys :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a hash (or a dictionary in terms of Python)

```
colors_dict = dict(colors)

if char_to_check in colors_dict:
    rgb_values = colors_dict[char_to_check]
    # do something
```

Comment: spot-on answer. Not really a duplicate since OP doesn't know that his data structure can be converted to dict simply.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah. Luckily for me he already had the data in the right format for instantiation.

Comment: Thanks. Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

While I like @hspandher answer, depending on the use, that solution may not be *the most efficient*. @hspandher solution may be efficient if you construct the dictionary once and query it multiple times. However, if you need to find the color value only once (in a large list) then a direct loop would be several times more efficient than constructing a `dict`:

```
for c, v in colors[::-1]:
    if c == 'b':
        print(v) # <- do something or return the value
        break
```

Comment: UV for explaining that building a dict is only efficient when used more than 1 time :)